# Script5007 error "object not found" only on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

When I first load a page I make an ajax call to bring some data for the client-side. The call is made to a different domain and the answer comes as JSONP. The call looks similar to:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url + "?callback=?",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            contentType: "application/javascript;charset=UTF-8",
            async: true,
            success: successCallback,
            error: errorCallback,
            cache: true,
            jsonpCallback: jsonCB
        });
```

'application/javascript' would be the possible culprit here as I did my research on the subject but this is present in a previous version of the code which never had this problem.
On all browsers except IE I receive the following error (sometimes, usually the first time and then the problem dissappears) :

```
script5007 object not found - line 1, char 1
```

The JSONP received looks like that:

```
func({"result":"abc"})
```

The param of the *func* is a valid JSON as I checked this using jslint.
Any idea will be highly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the object brackets `{ }` inside your `$.ajax` function. Modify it like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'',
    contentType: 'application/javascript;charset=UTF-8',
    crossDomain:true
     ......
});
```

The jQuery [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method either takes a url parameter and an optional parameter of additional options specified as an object, or an object parameter including the url.

Comment: The call was written from the top of my head as I don't have access to the source code. It surely has the brackets. I edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: @ArielChelsău Please post your original code if possible. Try viewing the source in the browser and pulling it from there if you have to. Without it, no one will clearly be able to diagnoise the problem.